# javascript insertAdjacentElement is not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

In my javascript code insertAdjacentElement is being used.
It's working quit fine in IE, but in chrome it works but not in expected way. it insert new html in somewhere else. so i want alternate of this method. I've also tried appendChild and insertBefore but in vain.

here is my code line

```
newPage = nd.insertAdjacentElement("beforeBegin", oNewItem);
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you are expecting to happen, perhaps in terms of the newPage, nd, oNewItem variables you use in your code?

Comment: i have 4,5 frames. on every click it produced new div(page) and past iframe into that newly created page.but in chrome it create new page but always paste iframe html into the first div(page).

Comment: It sounds like that might a problem caused by something that's going on in another part of your code. Would you be able to update the question with more of the javascript so the context is a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the equivalent would be

```
newPage = nd.parentElement.insertBefore(oNewItem, nd);
```

You can try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/faz23p97/

Comment: Could you explain what the result is, and how it is different to what you expected?

Comment: i have 4,5 frames. on every click it produced new div(page) and past iframe into that newly created page.but in chrome it create new page but always paste iframe html into the first div(page).

Answer (score -2):

The title should be changed in `"JavaScript DOM insertBefore isn't used properly"`.

That's because, even if you didn't put in your DOM, the browser automatically creates a `<tbody>` element that wraps the rows of the table. So, it happens that `#formtable` is not the parent of `#submitrow`, and that's why you get an error.

Try this:

```
formtable.tBodies[0].insertBefore(new_tr, submitrow);
```

Or, more generally:

```
submitrow.parentNode.insertBefore(new_tr, submitrow);
```

(In browsers that support it, there's even this one:

```
submitrow.insertAdjacentElement("beforeBegin", new_tr);
```

Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari and Opera support it, Firefox doesn't but it can be easily shimmed. I don't recommend using this stuff, anyway.)

And, as a general advice, always use the  tag when writing down tables:

```
<table id="formtable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Number : </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="submitrow">
            <td><input type="button" value="Add one more" onclick="addRow()" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Go!" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And, of course, `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` when you need them.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to concern an issue in IE - "It's working quit fine in IE"

Comment: The question doesn't seem to concern an issue with tables either?